# What is the inverse of $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x-1}$?

Tags: inverse, inverse-function

It is bijective so it should have one. I was solving some of my homework when I came upon this. The answer key had a question mark for the solution. I looked it up on Wolfram Alpha and there is a solution: $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{2x^2+1}{2x^2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{4x^2+1}}{2x^2}$

I tried to backtrack from the solution but I had no luck. Could someone point me on the right path?

Comment: You have $y=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x-1}$. Since $x\neq 1$ you have $y(x-1)=\sqrt{x}$. Now elevate to the power $2$ both memebers. Try to go on fiinding $x$. If you have trouble I will post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we need to properly set the domain and co-domain. The domain is
$$
D=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: x \ge 0, x \ne 1\} = [0,1[\cup]1,+\infty[
$$

and the co-domain is $D^* =\mathbb{R}$. As you have mentioned, $f:D \to D^*$ is one-to-one, and therefore invertible. An expression for the inverse can be obtained using the method mentioned by @SteveKim:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x-1} = y \Leftrightarrow y x -\sqrt{x} - y = 0 \Leftrightarrow y (\sqrt{x})^2-\sqrt{x}-y = 0,
$$

yielding
$$
\sqrt{x} = \dfrac{1\pm \sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}.
$$

When $y > 0$, we must choose the + sign and get, after squaring,
$$
x = 1+\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y^2}
$$

when $y < 0$, we must choose the - sign and get
$$
x = 1+\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y^2}.$$

Finally, the inverse is given by
$$
f^{-1}(y)=\begin{cases}
1+\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y^2},& y <0\\
0, & y=0\\
1+\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y^2}, & y >0
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The inverse function of $y=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x-1}$ is $x=\frac{\sqrt{y}}{y-1}$. What we need to do is to express this implicit-function form into the explicit form.

We can consider this as solving the equation $x = \frac{\sqrt{y}}{y-1}$ with the variable $y$. Note that this equation can be observed as
$$x(\sqrt{y})^2 - \sqrt{y} - x=0,$$
the quadratic equation with the variable $\sqrt{y}$. Apply the quadratic formula, and just square it!

Comment: Wow, I never would have thought of that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @StevenKim Although I understand what you meant, your first sentence is wrong.

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, I oversimplified the argument related to the domain and codomain of the function (might be the point you're talking about), just for giving the direction rather than strict logical writing.

Comment: @SteveKim I was talking about the part where you say that the inverse is given by $x = \sqrt{y}/(y-1)$. If this was true, you would be able to get an explicit expression for every inverse...